# Is there a way to know the style is declutter？

Tags: openlayers

When my feature requires a combination of text and line styles at the same time, the text is decluttered using overflow, but the lines still exist. I don't have a way to judge and hide the lines. Do you know of any other ways I can use this combination? it looks like this now.
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lppdh.png)

```
  this.layer = new VectorImageLayer({
    source: new VectorSource({ wrapX: false }),
    declutter: true,
    style: function (feature) {
      const { visible, rotation, type, sog, name, lonLat } =
        feature.getProperties();
      const currentZoom = self.map.getView().getZoom();
      const styles = [];

      const isSog = !!sog ? "sog" : "default";
      const icon = icons[type][isSog];
      if (currentZoom > self.minZoom && icon) {
        icon.setRotation((Math.PI * rotation) / 180);
        defaultStyle.setImage(icon);
        styles.push(defaultStyle);
      } else if (currentZoom <= self.minZoom) {
        styles.push(miniStyle);
      }

      if (currentZoom >= self.tooltipMinZoom && name && icon) {
        const pointStyle = tooltipStyle.Point;
        const pointText = pointStyle.getText();
        const radians = (Math.PI * rotation) / 180;
        const offsetX =
          self.tooltipOffsetX * Math.cos(radians) -
          self.tooltipOffsetX * Math.sin(radians);
        const offsetY =
          self.tooltipOffsetY * Math.sin(radians) +
          self.tooltipOffsetY * Math.cos(radians);
        pointText.setText(name);
        pointText.setOffsetX(offsetX);
        pointText.setOffsetY(offsetY);

        const startPixel = self.map.getPixelFromCoordinate(lonLat);
        startPixel[0] += offsetX;
        startPixel[1] += offsetY;
        const endPoint = self.map.getCoordinateFromPixel(startPixel);

        const lineStyle = tooltipStyle.LineString;
        lineStyle.setGeometry(new LineString([lonLat, endPoint], "XY"));

        styles.push(...[pointStyle, lineStyle]);
      }

      return visible ? styles : [];
    },
  });
```

I think this is all code that is relevant, and some style code that is not relevant unless you need it.

I want to know if it is possible to get the declutter of the style, or if there is another way to achieve this effect.